# Highest dictionary keys for each unique nested dictionary key value

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

How to select highest `mydict` keys for each unique `id` (i.e. B-4 and A-5)? We can assume the numbers increment.

```
mydict = {
    1: {'id': 'B',
        }, 
    2: {'id': 'B',
        }, 
    3: {'id': 'A',
        }, 
    4: {'id': 'B',
        }, 
    5: {'id': 'A',
        }, 
    }
```

My solution may not be most efficient

```
for k, v in reversed(mydict.items()):
    if v['id'] not in result:
        result[v['id']] = k
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the code to do it.

```
mydict = {
    1: {
        'id': 'B',
    }, 
    2: {
        'id': 'B',
    }, 
    3: {
        'id': 'A',
    }, 
    4: {
        'id': 'B',
    }, 
    5: {
        'id': 'A',
    }
}

results = {}

for key, value in mydict.items():
    if (value['id'] not in results) or (results[value['id']] < key):
        results[value['id']] = key

print(results)
```

Output:

```
{'B': 4, 'A': 5}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I fear this is not as efficient as solution in description.

Comment: @learning_python_self, I am afraid, the most efficient solution would require at least 1 loop because as per the data can't be sure of the keys and corresponding ids.

Comment: Or, if there're special cases like there are only a fixed amount of ids `['A', 'B']` which we can lookup, and if the keys are from `0` to `length_of_dict-1`, then code could be optimized further

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a new dictionary with the id's as key and the top level key as value.  Given that the top level dictionary is already ordered by ascending keys, the last value assigned to each id will be the last key found (i.e. the maximum for that id):

```
mydict = {
    1: {'id': 'B',
        }, 
    2: {'id': 'B',
        }, 
    3: {'id': 'A',
        }, 
    4: {'id': 'B',
        }, 
    5: {'id': 'A',
        }, 
    }

result = { d['id']:k for k,d in mydict.items() }

print(result)
           
{'B': 4, 'A': 5}
```